# exact differential equation on non simple connect domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is known that a first order differential equation 
$$
P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0
$$
is exact if and only if
$$
P_y(x,y)=Q_x(x,y)
$$
in a **simple connected** open set. Is it true also in **non** simple connect set? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. The standard counter example is $$P=\frac x{x^2+y^2}\, ,\;\;\; Q=\frac y{x^2+y^2}$$ on the unit disk without the origin.

Comment: but $f(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+y^2)$ is not a potential function?

Comment: Yes, it is....in any region not containing within it the origin. These notions usually go with the requirement of simply connected regions, and you can check it by yourself: the integral of the above around the uni is **not** zero...

Comment: so the exsistance of a potential function is not depend upon the fact that the region is simple connected?

Comment: @Boaz I'm not quite sure and it may well depend on definitions. I think the existence of "potential function" = our vector field is some function's gradient is well independent of the fact whether we're working on a s.c. region or not. Yet for existence of solutions, integrals and etc. it may be important to use this within a s.c. domain.